# Click on dynamically generated radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to alert some text when a dynamically generated radio button is checked .. here is the link from fiddle .. 
http://jsfiddle.net/z7cu3q0y/

```
function createRadioButtons(n)
{
    $("#radioContainer").empty();
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        radioButtons = "<p><input type='radio' class='"+n+"' name='"+n+"'>"+(i+1)+"</p>";
        $("#radioContainer").append(radioButtons);
    }
}    

$("#dropDown").on("change",function()
{
      createRadioButtons(parseInt($(this).val()));
});

$("#radioContainer input").on("change",function()
{
      alert("checked");
});
```

when i click on radio button i am not getting alert .. can any one of you please help me in taking a look ?

Thanks in advance,
Ashwin

Comment: Plenty of answers below, so I'll just explain things. The problem you're having comes from the fact that at the time you bind the event listener `$('#radioContainer input').on('change', ...)`, the radio button doesn't exist yet, so jQuery doesn't find it. The reason why the delegation answers below work is that you're binding the event listener to `#radioContainer`, which _does_ exist. Then when the click happens, you check to see if the clicked element was a radio button, which by this time does exist.

Answer (score 8):

Your code `$("#radioContainer input").on("change",function(){})`
will directly attach the event handler to the matching elements that are currently present in `DOM`.

To work with dynamically generated elements added in the future, You need to [delegate](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) your event handler to a common parent element:

```
$("#radioContainer").on("change","input",function(){
  alert("checked");
});
```

The above will attach the handler to `#radioContainer`, Whenever the corresponding event (*`change` in this case*)is triggered (*Usually propagated from the children*), it checks whether the event target matches the specified selector (*`input`* in this case) and invokes the handler accordingly.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7cu3q0y/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.on()` for dynamically generated elements like below. Here `.on()` will bind change event to all radio buttons which are inside `radioContainer`

```
$("#radioContainer").on("change","input[type=radio]",function()
{
      alert("checked");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/z7cu3q0y/5/)**

Comment: *Here .on() will bind change event to all radio buttons which are inside radioContainer* - not true.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code

```
$(document).on("change","#radioContainer input",function(){
 alert("checked");
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7cu3q0y/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the input defined as click area and radiocontainer as working area.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/don/z7cu3q0y/3/

Just remove input before `.on` and put inside of the function.

---

**jQuery:**

```
function createRadioButtons(n)
{
    $("#radioContainer").empty();
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        radioButtons = "<p><input type='radio' class='"+n+"' name='"+n+"'>"+(i+1)+"</p>";
        $("#radioContainer").append(radioButtons);
    }
}    

$("#dropDown").on("change",function()
{
      createRadioButtons(parseInt($(this).val()));
});

$("#radioContainer").on("change", 'input', function()
                              {
                                  alert("checked");
                              });
```